# Compiling Qt5 project without QT Creator

Tags: compilation, qt-creator, qt5, distro

We have built a large-ish program using QT Creator 5 on Fedora (easy install).  We now have to compile for older distro's including RH5 and RH6.

I realize that QT Creator doesn't support the older versions of libstdc++ which ship with RH5 and RH6.  However, can we still use make & qmake from the command line to compile our project under other distros?

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator gives you the commands.

Open Qt Creator and your project (on Fedora). Then go to the "`Projects`" tab (the one with a folder icon at the left of your window). The window should show you the compiling steps it uses for building your program (and the cleaning steps too). Most of the time. Copy those steps in a shell script, adapt it to your targeted plateform (RHEL in your case) and then compile the program by launching your script on the targeted plateform (i.e. RHEL). Otherwise you can using the traditional `qmake && make` on Red Hat.